# How should I model data for sharding?

Tags: database, language-agnostic, redis, sharding

I have a conceptual understanding of database sharding from reading high level docs, but I have yet to read much code or do any such hacking myself.

In [this article about using Redis as a primary datastore](https://moot.it/blog/technology/redis-as-primary-datastore-wtf.html), the author emphasizes that

> You need to design your data around sharding

I'm hung up about the design criteria:

- I'm not very familiar with SQL stuff, but if I were using a noSQL database that's only aware of keys and values/documents is my data already "shardable"?
- Or do the values/documents need to be of uniform schema as well?
- Are there other criteria that I'm missing?

The author also mentions that

> The most difficult part of this is clearly defining how you segment your data [into shards]. This is a very application specific problem

- Is "data segmentation" related/identical to the "data design" problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sharding in Redis is by nature much easier than in a relational database, as there is no relationship between data. You can define at application level the way data will be distributed amongst Redis instances according to your own algorithm. You can say it's related to the data design. By example you could say entities are sharded depending on their nature (Users in a database, Products in another one) or or according to their ids (Users with a name starting with A to L in a database, from M to Z in another).

As usual with Redis (and NoSQL databases in general) you have to design your data model according to the way you will request them.

There is a detailed article on data partitioning on [redis website](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning). It will be much more complete than any answer I could write :)

For what it's worth, I implemented myself a full web application using Redis as a primary datastore, as an experiment at first. It was a social network, had a multi-criteria search engine. I thought I would have to switch to a more traditional solution (like adding a relational database) at some point. I was nicely surprised this I hadn't to do it. Every use case I had to handle (including a search engine) was rather easily implemented using Redis. And Redis allowed me to achieve impressive performances. But I had to think a lot about data modeling, what data loss was acceptable or not (and create robust algorithm, to be able to restart transparently a process interrupted by a crash), how to limit memory consumption... and design my data according to this.

Last but not least, [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) is on it's way and may offer you a solution for sharding. But it's not production ready yet and will be limited compared to a single redis instance (only one database per instance by example).

Comment: Interesting.  I'll keep an eye on Redis Cluster - it might be just what I'm looking for in the future.  That Redis article is a good reference.